# what's difference between data and type in schema option mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

hello guys i'm a new person in mongoose. During while i watch on reset password tutorial by nodejs.
i founded schema option i never seem it before. in a tutorial, He just explain the data instead a type keyword option then i want to know what's difference between data and type in mongoose

and this what i founded

```
 password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    resetLink : {
        data : String,
        
    }
```

i have been looking for meaning of "data"properties, and i cannot seem explanation of it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What we see here is that the field `password` is a required string, while the field `resetLink` is the object that holds property `data` as a string.

That link should help you: [defining mongoose schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition)